# How do you check for prerequisites before installing a Sitecore module package?

Tags: packages

- How do you determine that prerequisites are met before allowing the packages to install?
- How do you stop the installation if conditions are not met?

Looking for an improved experience through the Installation Wizard. Obviously all of this could be checked by something like SPE.

#### Update

Would the use of the event `packageinstall:starting` be a good option? Perhaps make SPE run a script on this and then bail out of the installation when certain conditions are not met.

#### Update 2

I discovered that in SPE I can add an event subscriber in the config and then a script to go along with it. Throwing an error in the script causes the installation to stop. Unfortunately no decent errors are shown to the user.

[image: Sample]

#### Update 3

Apparently the installer events call `JobContext` to show dialogs. Either with SPE or some other previously installed module, you could achieve the desired behavior.

[image: Working dialog]

With some form of configuration you could have the **Prerequisite Checker** validate information before the installation completes.

[image: Config Settings]

Comment: The problem with the `packageinstall:starting` is it kicks off **before** anything from the package has been deployed, so what code would you be running? You could use SPE, but you can't guarantee SPE is installed... and even if it is then your package would need to an additional "prerequisites" file that SPE could extract and parse. I don't think there is a generic way to solve this.

Comment: So would need to create a new module called Prerequisite Checker that is installed immediately after a vanilla instance and use some kind of DSL to provide instructions.

Answer (score 1):

A Sitecore module installation package do not have any pre-installation steps. Thus, you cannot programmatically check for prerequisites. What I usually do is use the `<Readme></Readme>` section of the XML package definition file to document any prerequisites. This text is displayed in the installation wizard before the installation begins. The user can cancel the installation at this point to install any missing prerequisites.